# In what form an void pointer can be sent via pipe to another process in a different process address space

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net

I want my vb.net dll to get the data sent from c++ project(exe).Can any body help on in what form this void pointer can be sent via pipe. The void pointer corresponds to enums or structures. I have to get this structures/enums on the vb.net dll end. I have mentioned about using pipe. My question is as what type the pointed to data can be send over the pipe so that I can easily handle the received data at the vb.net dll end.

Answer (score 3):

A void pointer by definition corresponds to *nothing*, it is "opaque".

To transmit the data you need to *serialise* it, which means you need to know exactly what type of data the pointer pointed to originally.

Comment: can you please suggest me about correct method of to serialise if i have to send pointed to data which is a structure over a named pipe.....

Comment: @MartinJames you could, if you don't mind bloated data which can be difficult to parse.  Personally I'd go for JSON, or even raw binary if it's appropriate.